# Why does v8 report duplicate module strings in heap in my jest tests?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, heap-memory, v8

In the process of upgrading node (16.1.x => 16.5.0), I observed that I'm getting OOM issues from jest. In troubleshooting, I'm periodically taking heap snapshots. I'm regularly seeing entries in "string" for module source (same shallow/retained size). In this example screenshot, you can see that the exact same module (React) is listed 2x. Sometimes, the module string is listed even 4x for any given source module.

Upon expansion, it says "system / Map", which suggests to me *I think?* that theres some v8 wide reference to this module string? That makes sense--maybe. node has a require cache, jest has a module cache, v8 and node i'd assume... share module references? The strings and compiled code buckets do increase regularly, but I expect them to get GC'd. In fact, I can see that many do--expansion of the items show the refs belonging to GC Roots. But I suspect something is holding on to these module references, and I fear it's not at the user level, but at the tooling level. This is somewhat evidenced by observation that only the node.js upgrade induces the OOM failure mode.

- Why would my jest test have multiple instances of the same module (i am using --runInBand, so I don't expect multiple workers)
- What tips would you offer to diagnose further?

I do show multiple VM Contexts, which I think makes sense--I suppose jest is running some test suites in some sort of isolation.

[image: heap module]

[image: mutliple contexts]

I do not have a reproduction--I am looking for discussion, best-know-methods, diagnostic ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer some thoughts:

"system / Map" does *not* mean "some v8 wide reference". "Map" is the internal name for "hidden class", which you may have heard of. The details don't even matter here; TL;DR: some internal thing, totally normal, not a sign of a problem.

Having several copies of the same string on the heap is also quite normal, because strings don't get deduplicated by default. So if you run some string-producing operation twice (such as: reading an external file), you'll get two copies of the string. I have no idea what jest does under the hood, but it's totally conceivable that running tests in parallel in mostly-isolated environments has a side effect of creating duplicate strings. That may be inefficient in a sense, but as long as they get GC'ed after a while, it's not really a problem.

If the specific hypothesis implied above (there are several tests in each file, and jest creates an in-memory copy of the entire file for each executing test) holds, then a possible mitigation might be to split your test files into smaller chunks (1.8MB is quite a lot for a single file). I don't have much confidence in this, but maybe it'd be easy for you to try it and see.

More generally: in the screenshot, there are 36MB of memory used by strings. That's far from being an OOM reason.

It might be insightful to measure the memory consumption of both Node versions. If, for example, it used to consume 4GB and now crashes when it reaches 2GB, that would indicate that the limit has changed. If it used to consume 2GB and now crashes when it reaches 4GB, that would imply that something major has changed. If it used to consume 1.98GB and now crashes when it reaches 2.0GB, then chances are something tiny has changed and you just happened to get lucky with the old version.

Until contradicting evidence turns up, I would operate under the assumption that the resource consumption is normal and simply must be accommodated. You could try giving Node more memory, or reducing the number of parallel test executions.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a known issue of Jest at Node JS v16.11.0+ and has already been [reported to GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11956).